# Can an empty array check somehow precede an optional binding?

Tags: swift

Given that you have an array of optionals:

```
var values = [AnyObject?]
```

Can you use a `where` clause somehow before the optional binding, say, to check for a non-empty array? For example, I know that we can do this:

```
if !values.isEmpty {
    if let value = values[0] {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And we can chain a `where` filter after the optional binding:

```
// doesn't do you any good when the array is empty
if let value = values[0] where !values.isEmpty {
    // ...
}
```

I'd like to be able evaluate the `where` first, to prevent an array index out of range error:

```
// Not valid syntax
if where !values.isEmpty, let value = values[0] {
    // ...
}
```

Is there some form of syntax in Swift 1.2 or 2.x that allows me to express this in a valid manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
if let value = values.first {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Dude you get the gold star for showing me the obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @ybakos Thanks, It's not obvious if you don't know it though ;)

Comment: @ybakos Accept answer?